# how can I add sub heading in pandas in extracted dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is the dataframe which I extracted from a pdf. there are 3 subheadings in the pdf. have can I range, average and change as subcolumns in pettah, and 16 - June and 15-June in average columns. I want all the range average, change, 16-june and 15 June to make subheading columns. unnamed was given as default when converting the pdf into a dataframe.

```
Item    Unnamed: 0  Pettah  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Marandagahamula Unnamed: 3
0   0   Range   Average Change *    Range   Average Change *
1   0   16-Jun  16-Jun 15-Jun   0   16-Jun  16-Jun 15-Jun   0
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output?